# Scoverage set up for a gradle multi module project issue

Tags: scala, gradle, code-coverage, scalatest, scoverage

For a multi module project on Scala using gradle, there are integration tests in module `A` that call a method `X` from this module. This method in turn calls method `Y` from another module `B`. I'd expect both `X` and `Y` to get coverage but since `Y` is in a different module, it's showing as 0%.

Is there any way to solve this? Aggregation only works for the reports, but not the raw coverage. I've seen a workaround here for the maven plugin (running package first) but that option does not seem to be available in the gradle plugin.